# Mono<Optional<Object>> with switchIfEmpty

Tags: spring, java-8, option-type, spring-webflux, project-reactor

With the below implementation, the expectation is that, it would go to `switchIfEmpty` if `Mono<Optional<Item>>` is empty, but not working as expected.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getItemById(ServerRequest request) {
        JwtClaim claim = retrieveClaimFromRequest(request);
        String itemId = request.pathVariable("itemId");
        Mono<ServerResponse> notFound = ServerResponse.notFound().build();
        Mono<Optional<Item>> item = Mono.just(itemRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(itemId)));
        return item
                .flatMap(retItem -> ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(retItem))
                .switchIfEmpty(notFound);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a `Mono<Optional<Object>>`? The `bodyValue` will be set to an `Optional<Item>`, not to `Item`. Also is there a specific reason you are using `flatMap` instead of `map`?

Comment: Also, to what framework does `Mono` belong? I guess Reactor?

Comment: @Turing85, you are correct it gives Optional<Item>. What is the best way to handle it?

Comment: `Mono<Item> item = Mono.just(itemRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(itemId)).orElse(null));` could fix it, but is not null-safe. If you expect the `findById` to return something, you may want to throw an applicable exception by calling `orElseThrow(...)` instead.

Comment: I want to return NotFound reponse if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your current solution is that `Optional<Item>` is *always* returned and available, either with the actual content or an empty one, but the instance itself is *present* there.

The best way is using [`Mono.justOrEmpty(Optional)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#justOrEmpty-java.util.Optional-) which takes `Optional` as a parameter and creates either an empty `Mono` or the one with a content:

```
Mono<Item> item = Mono.justOrEmpty(itemRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(itemId)));

return item.flatMap(retItem -> ServerResponse.ok().build())
           .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
```

Effectively, it is as same as you flatmap `Mono<Mono<Item>>` using the result of `Optional::orElse`:

```
Mono<Optional<Item>> item = Mono.just(itemRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(itemId)));
    
return item.flatMap(opt -> opt.map(Mono::just).orElse(Mono.empty()))
           ...
```